# Why is it such a mission to backup a SQL Server 2008 Express database?

Tags: sql-server, backup, user-instance

I wouldn't describe myself as afraid of change - but afraid of new technologies? YES INDEED! Technologies from operating systems, to database servers just seem to become bugged, inefficient and backward the further they "progress"

**MSDE 2000** (what they might call "SQL 2000 Express" in today's world)

```
BACKUP [MyDatabase] TO FILE 'c:\backups\mybackup.backup'
```

**SQL 2008 EXPRESS**

Wait up! Its a 'user instance' - to back it up we need to attach it to a server instance
Wait up! To attach it we need SQL Management Studio Express (78MB download)
Wait up! When we login to our .\SQLEXPRESS server instance and try to attach our database it gives us an error that literally looks like a bug in our homebrew dev project:

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
>
> Cannot show requested dialog.
>
> ------------------------------ ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> Parameter name: nColIndex Actual value
>   was -1.
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.GridControl)

Can someone explain how to backup a user instance of a SQL Server 2008 Express database in T-SQL code?

(sorry if this comes across like a flame at ummmm, Microsoft - I'm actually a huge fan of theirs. Just really angry about things like this! please don't vote me down...)

Comment: There is no difference backing up MSDE or SQL2008 Express databases. You just need to log into right instance; for SQL 2005/2008 you can easily use sqlcmd to log on and execute T-SQL statements.

Comment: @Arvo: MSDE 2000 didnt have user instances, only server instances which meant that although you could SEE the mdf & ldf files, you couldnt connect to them without going through the server instance first. That made a big difference between SQL 2000 and successive database engines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOME KEY TIPS TO NOTE WHEN TRYING TO ACHIEVE USER INSTANCE BACKUP**

### a.) Connecting

Your connection string should look like this:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Database=MyDatabaseAlias
```

It is **essential** that your connection string gives the connection an alias `Database=MyDatabaseAlias` - this alias **cannot be duplicated** concurrently on the same machine or your connection may fail.

### b.) Backing Up

As pointed out above, the Transact SQL to backup a database is the same on SQL MSDE/2000/2005/2008/R2 - once you have your database attached and **aliased**!

```
BACKUP DATABASE MyDatabaseAlias TO DISK = 'c:\backups\mydatabase_20101117.backup'
```

Whats truly amazing is the bull$h!t errors you can get because your connection string doesnt have the alias `Database=MyDatabaseAlias` part.

e.g. Unable to open the physical file 'c:\Code\MyProject\App_Data\MyDatabase.mdf' Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

### c.) **Restoring**

```
USE [master]; RESTORE DATABASE MyDatabaseAlias FROM DISK = 'c:\backups\mydatabase_20101117.backup'  WITH REPLACE
```

**Do not forget** the all essential `USE [master];` at the beginning of this statement (and note that its **all on one line** for those executing the command from a `DataContext` or similar) If you do, it wont be able to overwrite the existing database because you'll still be connected to it.

Once again, the assortment of **totally misleading errors** you might receive here, due to an invalid connection string, is endless.

Answer (score 1):

Um, if it's a user instance, then the simplest backup strategy is to copy the file. (whilst it's not connected to SQL Server).

If you need a more comprehensive backup strategy (e.g. transactional backups), then you really should be looking at a more comprehensive database (e.g. a "normal" one attached to a full SQL Server instance)

Comment: Unfortunately because its part of a website, its connected to SQL Server most of the time, otherwise I'd do that for sure :) I dont need a more comprehensive backup strategy, I just want to be able to do what I could 10 years ago in MSDE 2000 :P